# C# insert into Table from Dataset

Tags: c#, sql

Is this the Correct way of Coding...?? its Working 100%
fine.. But How Do i Shorten some more so that it looks nice....

and how do i check the Condition that..... if "REGID is already
present in table it should not add that column it should update the
 column....

```
if (DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{


       for (int i = 0; i < DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
       {
                DataAccess.Command cmdInsert = new Oca.DataAccess.Command();
                cmdInsert.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmdInsert.CommandString = "INSERT INTO STATUS (RigID,RigName,GroundDistance,DrillingSupervisor,DrillingEngineer,GeoSteering,Directional,MudCompany,OHLogs,JobIDRec,County,Area,WellName,Slot_Conductor,SurfaceLegalLocation,LocationType,State_Province,SurfaceLocation_Slot,Field,ReserveCategory,JOA,Well_Type,Land_Expiration,WI,NRI,Drilling_Permit,Unit_AlternateApproval,AFE,c_CALLS,c_STKD,c_WL,c_PLAT,c_DP,c_GP,c_DRILLPROG,c_SIMOPS,c_LOC,c_PMT,c_UNITAPP,c_AFE,c_TITLE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                //DataSet DsInsert = DataAccess.GetDataSet(dCorpID, cmdInsert);
                // DataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(dCorpID, cmdInsert);
                cmdInsert.AddParameter("RigID",DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmdInsert.AddParameter("RigName",DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmdInsert.AddParameter("GroundDistance",DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmdInsert.AddParameter("DrillingSupervisor",DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmdInsert.AddParameter("DrillingEngineer", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmdInsert.AddParameter("GeoSteering", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                cmdInsert.AddParameter("Directional", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                 cmdInsert.AddParameter("MudCompany", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                 cmdInsert.AddParameter("OHLogs", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                 cmdInsert.AddParameter("JobIDRec", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][9].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                 cmdInsert.AddParameter("County", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][10].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                 cmdInsert.AddParameter("Area", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][11].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("WellName", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][12].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("Slot_Conductor", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][13].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("SurfaceLegalLocation", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][14].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("LocationType", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][15].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("State_Province", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][16].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("SurfaceLocation_Slot", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][17].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("Field", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][18].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("ReserveCategory", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][19].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("JOA", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][20].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);                                  
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("Well_Type", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][21].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("Land_Expiration", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][22].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                  cmdInsert.AddParameter("WI", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][23].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                   cmdInsert.AddParameter("NRI", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][24].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmdInsert.AddParameter("Drilling_Permit", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][25].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmdInsert.AddParameter("Unit_AlternateApproval", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][26].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmdInsert.AddParameter("AFE", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][27].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_CALLS", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][28].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_STKD", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][29].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                      cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_WL", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][30].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_PLAT", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][31].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_DP", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][32].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_GP", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][33].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_DRILLPROG", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][34].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_SIMOPS", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][35].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                     cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_LOC", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][36].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_PMT", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][37].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_UNITAPP", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][38].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                    cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_AFE", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][39].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);
                   cmdInsert.AddParameter("c_TITLE", DSDBMax.Tables[0].Rows[i][40].ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input);

                   DataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(dCorpID, cmdInsert);




                    }
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a SqlBulkCopy() and column mapping if I were you.

Something like:

```
 using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(
   {   
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add("dtcolumnname", "sqlcolumnname");


        copy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE";
        copy.WriteToServer(table);
    }
```

Comment: in this case copy.ColumnMappings.Add("dtcolumnname", "sqlcolumnname"); will come 41 times(for my program) right..?

Comment: It depends.  If you have the same layout in your datatable that you have in the SQL table, then you don't have to do any column mapping at all.  Otherwise, you'll have to specify.

Comment: my source and and destination tables are exactly same.. how do i do..?

Comment: much easier- you simply eliminate the "copy.ColumnMappings.Add" bit altogether, and it will just do the table column-for-column

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line of code to:

```
 cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This should do the trick

Comment: His code already works- he's asking for an easier way to do it